# Load jQuery in PHP page - no head tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

This is probably super simple answer, but I just can't figure this out.

Basically, I've got a php page only starting with opening `<?php` tag.

I've got a jquery script that I need to call on this page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('input[name="_manage_item"]').click(function() {
     $('input[name="_item"]')[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();
     });
</script>
```

From what I researched, I need to load the script by placing

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

into the `<head>` tags of the page.

But my page doesn't have the html `<head>` or `<body>` tags. Where do I call the script then ?

I tried to place it in front of the opening `<?php` tag, but that broke the page.

What is the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: Please share your complete code.

Comment: I assume this is just HTML code inserted into a complete HTML page. Wordpress should already have a loaded jQuery library. Maybe `$` isn't defined and you need to use `jQuery` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your javascript outside the `php` tags at the bottom of you page. But when you use the php in a web page, you should add the `html` and `head` and `body` tags. A simple php page could look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- stylesheets and javascript -->
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    //You php-code
  ?>
  <!-- scripts at the end of the page to let the side load faster -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $('input[name="_manage_item"]').click(function() {
     $('input[name="_item"]')[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Relying on your `wordpress` tag, I suggest you to read [this article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript). There are described all details concerning `javascript` usage within `wordpress`. Probably the most common way is to use [`wp_register_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function.

> The safe and recommended method of adding JavaScript to a WordPress generated page, and WordPress Theme or Plugin, is by using wp_enqueue_script().

I would  also advise you to merge your code to a distinct file, and load it straight after `jquery` library. It is a good practice, because in such a way browser can cache your script and would not download it on every page request. You should also wrap it into a [`$( document ).ready()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript) function, to be sure that it will be executed only only when document is in ready state.